# Strange problem with Xcode 12 and iOS 14, error Coresimulator and more

Tags: cordova, ios14, xcode12, cordova-ios

I created an app with Cordova that has bugs with iOS 14 and I need to update it.

However, this problem that he presents to me is very strange and I don't think Cordova is the problem. The previous project opens quietly, starts but has bugs. For this I have made the update to the platform version ios 6.1.1

When I open the project and then test everything with the simulator, I always get the same error. I have no more ideas.

[image]

Comment: This problem has been solved.

Comment: Is it worth adding an answer? Maybe it will help other people.